# join two entities jpa spring postgresql

Tags: spring, postgresql-9.5

Hello im tring to make a join with two entities to make a findById() and I don't understand why it creates a new column all the time

SOLVED with
   `@OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "username")`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authorities")
public class RoleEntity implements Serializable {   
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Id
@Column(name="username")
private String user_id;
@Column(length = 45, unique = true)
private String authority;

public RoleEntity(String user_id, String authority) {

    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.authority = authority;
}

public RoleEntity() {

}
```

//getter and setter

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UsuarioEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
private String username;
@Column(length = 60, unique = true)
private String password;
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="authorities",
          joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name="username")
          )
private RoleEntity roles;
```

//getter and setter

Comment: If you want help, you really need to clarify your question.

Comment: Here's how to define a OneToOne association between two entities: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one